# I have two questions about Calculus, one is on power series and the other is on arc length

Tags: calculus, power-series, arc-length

Problem 1: Find a closed form for the power series $\sum_{n=2}^{\infty} \tfrac{x^n}{(n-1)n}$.  I already found the first two derivatives, but am unsure where to go from here.

Problem 2: Find the length of the curve given by the equation $y= \int_{ -\pi}^{x}\sqrt{\cos(t)} \mathrm dt$ for x between $-\pi$ and $\pi$. I am using the fundamental theorem of calculus to evaluate the integral, and then I will plug that back into the arc length formula, but I'm stuck on how to evaluate the integral.

Also, apologies in advance for not formatting properly, I didn't know how.

Comment: Please put your two questions as separate questions. Thanks!

Comment: Something's not right with the second question: $\sqrt{\cos(t)}$ is undefined for $t$ between $-\pi$ and $-\frac{\pi}{2}$ and between $\frac{\pi}{2}$ and $\pi$. So this function has an empty domain, and there's not much of a curve...

Answer (score 1):

Your double differential should result in a Geometric Series, the closed form of which you should know, so just integrate that twice.

Hint: via a change of bound-variable:  $$\sum_{n=2}^\infty x^{n-2} ~=~ \sum_{m=0}^\infty x^m$$

---

For the second, you need to evaluate the arc length via:

$$s= \int_{-\pi}^{\pi} \sqrt{1-\left(\dfrac{\mathrm d y}{\mathrm d x}\right)^2}\mathrm d x\qquad\text{When }y=\int_{-\pi}^x \sqrt{\cos t~}\mathrm d t$$

You do not need to integrate anything to find $y$; you do not even need to find $y$.

Just determine what $\dfrac{\mathrm d y}{\mathrm d x}$ equals via the fundamental theorem.

Comment: Nobody can find this $y$ -- it's ill-defined.

Comment: So would the closed form be x^(m+2)/(m+1)(m+2), or should I substitute back m=n-2? Oh wait no because that just puts me back where I started.

Comment: @Sdj Today's Keywords: "Geometric Series"